# Subspaces and convergence in weak* topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I would like to ask some questions regarding convergence in the weak* topology and subspaces.

Let $X$ be a normed space with subspace $A \subset X$. Assume $X$ is endowed with the weak* topology. Let $\{u_{m}\}_{m}$ be a sequence in $X$.

1. If $u_{m} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $A$ then since $X$ is not necessarily first-countable in the weak* topology then would I be right in stating that  $u$ is not necessarily in $A$?
2. If $u_{m} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $X$ then does that imply that $u_{m} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $A$ if $\{u_{m}\}_{m} \subset A$? Similarly, if $u_{m} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ then does that imply that $u_{m} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $X$?
3. Would question 2 require that $A$ is closed in $X$?

I am trying to apply this to Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and closed subspace $W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$. Any assistance or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. You assume that $u_n\overset{w^*}{\to} u$ in $A$ and then asks if $u\in A$. Of course, $u\in A$, because of the assumption.
2. Yes. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714942/weak-convergence-in-a-subspace).
3. No. Carefully read the proof given in the link.

Comment: For 1. Say for example if $A$ is open in $X$ and $u_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $A$ with $u \in \partial A$? Would one not write $u_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $A$ in that case as well?

Comment: No. For example $A=\operatorname{Ball}_{\ell_2}(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$. Consider $u_n=e_n\in A$, then $u_n\overset{w^*}{\to} 0=u\in\partial{A}=\{0\}$. But $u\notin A$.

Comment: Okay, so it would make more sense to write $u_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $X = {\text{Ball}}_{l_{2}(0,1)}$ where $\{u_{n}\}_{n} \subset A$?

Comment: No, in your notation $X$ is normed space, not a ball

Comment: Yes, but I understand. $u_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $A$ would imply that the convergence is related to the subspace topology and therefore it requires that $u_{n}, u \in A$. If $u_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ with $\{u_{n}\}_{n} \subset A$ but $u \in X \setminus A$ then this would be convergence with respect to the topology endowed on $X$. Is that the point of your example?

Comment: Yes. And by the way, I should say that if $A$ is not a linear subspace the there is only one way to put weak* topology on $A$ - it is the subspace topology. If $A$ is a linear subspace you can pconsider two toplogies which could get the name weeak* topology: the subspace topology, and the weak* topology of the normed space $A$ (just forget that $A$ is embedded in $X$). Fortunately both topologies coincide.

Comment: I see. If $A$ is not linear it requires that the weak* topology is obtained from $X$, if $A \subset X$. But if $A$ is linear we can consider the initial topology on $A$, where the mappings are taken from the continuous dual of $A$. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: This is exactly what I said earlier.